# How to use Linq GroupBy() to return GroupKey + GroupKeyItem + GroupList?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a **list of products** with **many options** which belong to different **option groups**. For display purposes **each group** also has a **sort order**.

My question is how do I create a list using **Linq GroupBy()** or another Linq Method to return the **Group Key** and **Group Sort Order** along with a list of **Options** for products in my list? All of the examples I have found only return a Group Key and List of Group Items.

Here's what I have so far:

```
productList = db.Products.Where(p => p.Active)ToList();
productListOptions = productList.SelectMany(p => p.Options).Distinct().ToList();    
var groupedOptions = from o in productListOptions
    group o by o.OptionGroup into g
    select new { OptionGroupName = g.Key.Name, OptionGroupSortOrder = g.Key.SortOrder, OptionList = g.ToList() };
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add test data and the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var model = db.Products
  .Include(p=>p.Options)
  .Include(p=>p.Options.Select(o=>o.OptionGroup))
  .Where(p=>p.Active);

foreach(var product in model)
  foreach(var optiongroup in product
    .GroupBy(p=>p.Options.OptionGroup)
    .OrderBy(og=>og.SortOrder))
  {
    // Do stuff at start of group
    foreach(var option in optiongroup)
      // Do stuff for each option
    // Do stuff at end of group
  }
```